# Web Service as an intermediate between an Android client and a MySQL server database

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I am developing an Android client to connect to a database (in my case MySQL server). The nice approach is using a Web Serive between them.

I found some nice reason for it here : 
[Best way to access a remote database: via webservice or direct DB-access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689539/best-way-to-access-a-remote-database-via-webservice-or-direct-db-access)

Elad wrote nice reasons such as complexity and security around this approach. Can you give me some new advice around these approaches and let me know about the source of your ideas, since Elad did not provide any source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest reason is that a JDBC connection needs to be stable. And mobile connections are not stable enough. Thus using an intermediate web service is a good option. Providing a rest service around some database will provide you with a secure, stable, standard way to access your data.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Snicolas can you provide me some official web site or papers in the web about your approach ?

Comment: this page ? :) or the one you metionned. I wouldn't say that science papers are useless in computer science. Not all, but they are concerned with theoretical problems of a different kind. Here you can find the cream of the java/android community sharing its experience on how to make programs working. That's quite a reference