# server-client in android ( except socket programming )

Tags: android, client-server

I have a project for the school. I must design a server-client system for android client- linux server or android client- android server. I see a lot of document about socket programming but i'm not looking for that. I wanna find a way like RMI. How can i do this?

( I tried to use Binder or AIDL but couldn't understand that are these effective for me.)

thanks

Comment: Client should use several methods of server like remote invocation

Comment: still too broad. May you find an architectural style and then ask about the implementation.

Comment: I couldn't understand. Are you talking about design patterns like Proxy Pattern, Mediator Pattern, Bridge Pattern ?

Comment: No. Its about the architecural style like REST, RPC etc.

Comment: I suggest you to use REST since it is simpler to work with, more flexible and lighter. [More On REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942839.aspx). Are you supposing to develop an enterprise applications?

Comment: can i do this using web service, json?

Comment: Yes exactly. Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955699/need-advice-talk-to-mysql-server-database-from-my-android-app/11962324#11962324) and let me know if there is any question.

Comment: Client should use methods of server sometimes easily. Does this form support this?

Comment: Can i use REST for using methods or should I use JSON-RPC?

Comment: Ali, i suppose to develop an enterprise app