# Choosing Best Storage Type in Android

Tags: android, xml, database, sqlite, parsing

There are many similar questions about this issue but I have clear points about my question to ask you.

I am new at Android development and before only I developed small applications which store small sized data. For example country List, calendar, birthday reminder etc. I stored my small data in single XML file and I parsed it with easy methods. This was enough for me. But for my Mobile Application Development Course I took a project which will store huge static data.

Specifications of my project will like these:

- There are about 200 entities.
- Each entity has about 20 sub categories which they stored in text format.
- Each sub category has about 30-sub categories which they stored again in text format.
- Also for each parent entity I will have 2-3 image

If I calculate simply, I have to store 200 X 20 X 30 = 120.000 static data for my application and data does not change. This is only install and use application. Online data interaction is not necessary. (If there are some changes for data I will relase major updates in long periods of time.)

**My question is about storing method.**

Which way should I choose? SQLite or XML parsing? For your answer can you explain advantages / disadvantages for your choice?

Comment: "Online data interaction is not necessary" - but highly advisable. Do you really need that much for your application to work? I'd highly recommend you to store the data on a server, download only that data that a user needs and cache it on the device.

Comment: @Egor This is good idea but my application is a kind of reference book which about countries and storing their specific data. I want to store my data on local, so it can be reachable everytime. Also I do not know anything about server and phone comminication. I have no more time to rearch these concepts :)

Comment: I suggest also to store data on the server. what if you decide to develop an iPhone or windows phone app. You can use the same data on your server. You can check [an example of how to talk to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955699/need-advice-talk-to-mysql-server-database-from-my-android-app/11962324#11962324). You can also have a offline mode in your application using content provider.

Comment: @hakiko, Then at the moment your best bet is SQLite database, as described in Joe Malin's answer. But later on, if you consider maintaining your project, you will see the benefits of storing the data on the server. In case you need to change anything in the data, you'll force your users to reinstall your app, and that's annoying.

Comment: @Egor and Ali assume, If I choose server-side storing, which consepts should I know? I am good at MySQL but before I did not develop server relational application for Android. Is it difficult for me? As far as I understand I will create MySQL or different DMBS and my application will talk with JSON or XML? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting project, although not necessarily realistic.

To manage a large amount of "static" data, you'll want a database. XML parsing forces you to store the data in memory, which means that you have to read it into memory on a regular basis. Remember that you can't count the in-memory data being around when the user goes to your app; Android may have destroyed your app previously.

On the other hand, you can use an SQLite database on disk directly from your app. It's persistent, even if your app goes away. You'll have to load the database once, when you install the app.

Consider wrapping your SQLite database in a content provider. This will, among other things, allow you to do asynchronous queries using a CursorLoader.

Comment: My decision overlaping with your thought. I asked this question on more forums, QA platforms and chat rooms. For my huge data, community is refering SQLite. Probably I will choose SQLite after little more answers:)