# Android app development(web services)

Tags: android, web-services

I have developed a RESTful web services for a temperature sensor. The basic work done here is, the sensed data from the sensor is stored in a database and provided to user in say as a localhost.

I want to develop a android application to view these data either from my database or localhost.

I would like to know if this is possible and if so where can I start my work on this?

Comment: do you have any thoughts already?

Comment: You can take a look on my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955699/need-advice-talk-to-mysql-server-database-from-my-android-app/11962324#11962324). That could help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you want to being able to see the data from your database in your android application. In that case I suggest you to use the RESTful web service that you developed and in your Android application use a [Http Client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to consume the data stored in your database. Here's an [example](http://hmkcode.com/android-internet-connection-using-http-get-httpclient/)