# how can i connect MSSQL or SQL SERVER to android

Tags: android

I want to connect my android application to MSSQL SERVER 2008 on local pc.

But i didnt get any proper solutions. `Some is saying use jdbc i have tried it but it is not work for mssql server`

If any one is knowing with step by step process. ?

Thank you

Comment: Well as far as know, you need to use restful services to create a JSON abject using c#, java, php whatever language you are using with MySQL, MsSQL etc... Even if you can do, it will not be effective to use it with mobile devices. So, try to search for Restful Web Services with Java, C# using MsSQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955699/need-advice-talk-to-mysql-server-database-from-my-android-app/11962324#11962324

Comment: possible duplicate of [connect to sql server from android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492417/connect-to-sql-server-from-android)